# PowerBI how to circumvent report filter and use query output as input

Tags: powerbi

In a report for a specific customer, I show the top-3 countries where his fraud is originating from. The table I use for this is called CustomerFraudCountry and constists of daily counts of how many times a country was included in a fraud cases, per country, per customer, per date.

---

Example data:

Id    Date         CustomerId              Country             Occurence

1     01-01-2017  1                              United States     10

2     01-01-2017  1                              Canada              7

3     01-01-2017  2                              United States     8

etc...

---

A report level filter is used to filter on CustomerId and a certain Date range.

So let's say for my CustomerId = 1, and a certain Date range 01-01-2017 until 31-05-2017 selected, I have a top-3 countries of

1. United States
2. Canada
3. Mexico,

visualized in some bar chart.

What I would love to do know, but I am totally stuck trying to do, is to show a pie chart that shows the top-10 customers (excluding CustomerId = 1) that have the most fraud cases uploaded with these top-3 countries (United States, Canada, Mexico).

There are currently two problems I cannot seem to find a solution for:

1. How to circumvent my report filter
2. How to use the outcome of some visual (/query) as input for another visual. I.e. rank my table using the dynamically determined countries 'United States', 'Canada', and 'Mexico'.

I would be very pleased to hear any ideas or suggestions. Even if you think it is impossible to do, please share any ideas of an workaround, while still allowing for dynamic changing of data, i.e. Date and CustomerId.

Note: I use DirectQuery

---

My current workaround for a better understanding of my problem:
[image]

Required: 
The 'Similar merchants' graph without having to hard-code the two visual filters, i.e. 1) Country, 2) Merchant/Custeromer Name. Both values should be dynamically set instead of set hard-coded.